# Multiples datos en un ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Hola estoy intentando guardar datos y son 4 inputs así que tengo 4 datos pero al poner el alert antes de insertar solo me trae un dato, quiero saber cual es la sintaxis correcta para llamar varios "data":

```
function llamada_ajax(){
    // alert(chain);
    $.ajax({
           async:true,
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "html",
           contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
           url:"?ajax=TipoRegimen_agregar_proceso",
           data:{"chain":chain,"chain2":chain2,"chain3":chain3,"chain4":chain4},
           beforeSend:cargando,
           success:llegada,
           timeout:4000,
           error:problemas
         }); 

  return false;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá el php que mando a llamar

```
<?php

$nom=$_POST['chain'];
$regimen=$_POST['chain2'];
$fechai=$_POST['chain3'];
$fechaf=$_POST['chain4'];
// echo "Nombre:".$nom;
$insert="insert into c_TipoRegimen (c_TipoRegimen,Descripcion,Fecha_InVig,Fecha_FinVig) values('$regimen','$nom','$fechai','$fechaf')";
mysqli_query($conn,$insert) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

echo"true";
?>
```

Comment: Solo sale un dato porque solo estas poniendo una variable en el alert.

Comment: no amigo mira, pondre el codigo completo para que se entienda mejor

Comment: no puedo poner todo el codigo pero aqui pongo el alert

function guardar(){
 tomar_datos();
  alert(chain,chain2,chain3,chain4);
 llamada_ajax();
}

Comment: Intenta poner `+` en lugar de `,`

Comment: No entiendo nada. En el  `alert` verás lo que devuelvas del servidor, en este caso estás diciendo solamente esto: `echo"true";` Eso es lo único que recibirás en respuesta y nada más. Y tampoco veo la función `llegada` que es donde deberías manejar la respuesta de Ajax. Ni veo a qué `alert` te refieres.

Comment: Esto es correcto así: `data:{"chain":chain,"chain2":chain2,"chain3":chain3,"chain4":chain4}` para fines de prueba puedes crear una variable y pasarla en `data`. Incluso, no necesitas poner comillas a la izquierda, así iría bien: `var datos:{chain:chain, chain2:chain2, chain3:chain3, chain4:chain4};` luego puedes revisarlo en consola, con `console.log(datos);` para ver el resultado tienes que abrir la consola. Si no asume alguna de las variables tienes que ver como las estás asignando. En cuanto Ajax, puedes pasarlo así: `data: datos` una vez creada la variable...

Comment: Verifica que tus inputs tengan definido correctamente el id

Comment: El parámetro `url` también es raro: `url:"?ajax=TipoRegimen_agregar_proceso"`  ¿cómo se llama el archivo?  ¿? Pon ahí la ruta del archivo y parece que quieres pasar esto como dato también: `ajax=TipoRegimen_agregar_proceso` lo puedes agregar a la variable `datos` así: **`data:{"chain":chain,"chain2":chain2,"chain3":chain3,"chain4":chain4, ajax: 'TipoRegimen_agregar_proceso'}`** y quitar esto de paso: `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",`

Answer (score 0):

yo antes de realizar la llamada a ajax, cojo los valores del formulario tal que así:

```
function cargarbustrabajador() {
    var em = document.getElementById("selectempresa");
    var empresa=em.options[em.selectedIndex].value;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/rellenartrabajadores.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { empresa:empresa }
    }).done(function(result) {
        $('#selecttrabajador').html(result);
        $('#selecttrabajador option[value=""]').html("Elige").attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#selecttrabajador').selectpicker('refresh')
    });
```

por ejemplo asi llamo yo a un ajax en una aplicacion antigua
No veo por ningún lugar que pases los datos, por eso da el error, espero te sirva, si no comenta y lo arreglamos juntos

Comment: Si hago algo parecido, mira el codigo completo: actualmente me manda para problemas al guardar. https://codeshare.io/ayMZEq

Comment: vale, ahora lo veo coges los datos en la tomar_datos , la llamas desde guardar, y luego llamas a la funcion llamada_ajax(), puedes hacer un alert de  alert(chain); dentro de llamada_ajax() para ver que se reciben los datos correctamente? y si es así puedes hacer un var_dump($_POST['chain']) en el php TipoRegimen_agregar_proceso para ver que el php lo recibe correctamente? un saludo

Comment: Lo del alert dentro del llamada_ajax() si muestra el valor muy bien, al hacer el var dump en el php me fue imposible verlo ya que con ajax solo lo manda al lamar para insertar los datos no se ve como tal en la interfaz

Comment: miralo desde la pestaña network de la consola de desarrollador de chrome( F12 y luego pestaña network) ahí se ven todas las llamadas ajax, y si haces click podras ver el error que de y el var_dumpç

Comment: Sale esto: Request Data
MIME Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
chain
chain2
chain3
chain4 

Pero sale con el 200 de ok

Comment: function cargarbustrabajador() {
    var em = document.getElementById("selectempresa");
    var empresa=em.options[em.selectedIndex].value;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/rellenartrabajadores.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { empresa:empresa }
    }).done(function(result) {
        $('#selecttrabajador').html(result);
        $('#selecttrabajador option[value=""]').html("Elige").attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#selecttrabajador').selectpicker('refresh')
    }); por ejemplo asi llamo yo  a un ajax en una aplicacion antigua. Te lo actualizo en la respuesta